# How to identify points on a pca residual qqplot in R?

Tags: r, pca, identify

I plotted the residuals of my pca with the following function: plot(resid(pca1)). And here is the graph I have.

I would like to identify the two outliers on the top right but I don't know how to do that. Knowing that the "identify" function does not seem to work with plot(resid()) functions.

PS: I don't know why the first points are labeled. It was like that automatically.

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you tell us how you calcualted the PCA? Did you use princomp or prcomp or an other library?

Comment: try plot(hatvalues(pca1)) if pca1 is a model itself.

Comment: Sure, I used the principal function of the psych library:  pca1 = psych::principal(data, nfactors=2, rotate = "varimax", scores = TRUE